# Sympy: TypeError: can't convert expression to float

Tags: python, sympy, solver

I am trying to solve a simple system of equations in sympy but I'm getting the error: "TypeError: can't convert expression to float".

```
import sympy as sy
q0,q1,x,y = sy.symbols('q_0,q_1,x,y')
s = sy.Matrix([sy.Eq(x-sy.cos(q0)-sy.cos(q0+q1),0),
            sy.Eq(y-sy.sin(q0)-sy.sin(q0+q1),0)]);
sol = sy.solve(s.subs({x:2,y:0}),q0,q1)
```

The solution should be (0,0). I am using sympy version: 0.7.6-git.

Comment: Maybe if you use the [angle sum identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) and replace `sy.cos(qi)`, `sy.sin(qi)` with variables, you can solve the polynomial equations first.

Comment: @unutbu but then I would have 4 variables and 2 equations. Variables c1,c2,s1,s2 = cos(q1),cos(q2),sin(q1),sin(q2).

Comment: You could substitute `{sin(q1): sy.sqrt(1-sy.cos(q1)**2)}`; I tried this and got sy.solve to solve for cos(q0), cos(q1) and return (1,1), but also a complicated (bogus?) solution. I'll post it below to show what I mean, but the solution is incomplete.

Comment: Curious, because that error doesn't pop up in sympy version 0.7.5. Does the error show up for `solve` or already at an earlier step? You might want to file a bugreport...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial solution:

```
import sympy as sy

q0, q1, x, y = sy.symbols('q_0,q_1,x,y', real=True, positive=True)
cq0, cq1, sq0, sq1 = sy.symbols('cq0, cq1, sq0, sq1', real=True)
s = sy.Matrix([sy.Eq(x - sy.cos(q0) - sy.cos(q0 + q1), 0),
               sy.Eq(y - sy.sin(q0) - sy.sin(q0 + q1), 0)])
# Matrix([
# [x - cos(q_0) - cos(q_0 + q_1) == 0],
# [y - sin(q_0) - sin(q_0 + q_1) == 0]])

s2 = sy.expand_trig(s).subs({
    sy.cos(q0) : cq0
    , sy.cos(q1) : cq1
    , sy.sin(q0) : sy.sqrt(1-cq0**2)
    , sy.sin(q1) : sy.sqrt(1-cq1**2)})

solns = set(sy.solve(s2.subs({x: 2, y: 0}), cq0, cq1))
for soln in solns:
    print(soln)
```

yields

```
(1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite the matrix entries in terms of exp and don't check the answer, it works well:

```
>>> print(filldedent(
... solve(s.applyfunc(lambda x:x.rewrite(exp)).subs({x:2,y:0}), q0, q1, check=0)))

[(0, 0), (zoo, pi), (pi, 0), (-I*log(-sqrt(exp(zoo))), zoo),
(-I*log(sqrt(exp(zoo))), zoo)]
```